Prove the density of $(X,Y,Z)$ has the form $q(z)r(z,x)s(z,y)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent given $\sigma(Z)$
The definition of conditionally independent:
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space,and Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathcal{A}$.
Let $X,Y$ be two real variables,we say that $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent given $\mathcal B$ if, for any nonnegative measurable functions $f$ and $g$,we have:$$\mathbb{E}[f(X)g(Y)|\mathcal{B}]=\mathbb{E}[f(X)|\mathcal{B}]\mathbb{E}[g(Y)|\mathcal{B}]$$

Question:Let $X,Y,Z$ be real random variables.Assume the random vector
$(X,Y,Z)$ has a density which is positive on $\mathbb{R}^3.$ Prove
that the following is equivalent:
(1)$X$ and $Y$ are conditionally
independent given $\sigma(Z)$.
(2)The density of $(X,Y,Z)$ can be
written in the form:$$p(x,y,z)=q(z)r(z,x)s(z,y)$$where $q$ is the
density of $Z$ and $r, s$ are positive measurable functions on
$\mathbb{R}^2$.

Here is my attempt:I can prove $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$ is true,but it is hard for me to give the proof of the other direction:
Assume $(1)$ is true,to determine $p(x,y,z)$,let $f,g,h$ be nonnegative measurable functions and compute:$$\mathbb E[f(X)g(Y)h(Z)]=\iiint_{\mathbb R^3}f(x)g(y)h(z)p(x,y,z)dxdydz$$On the other hand,we have:$$\begin{align}
\mathbb E[f(X)g(Y)h(Z)]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[ f(X)\mid Z]\cdot \mathbb E[g(Y)\mid Z]\cdot h(Z)]
\end{align}$$What should I do to simplify the RHS?I am stuck here.
Any help would be appreciated.

Note:This problem comes from Measure Theory, Probability, and Stochastic Processes (Jean-François Le Gall) p253


Where is that from? The $q(z)$ looks totally superfluous. When  $p(x,y,z)=r(z,x)s(z,y)$ then, conditional on $Z,,$ the joint distribution of $X$ an $Y$ is a product measure and $X$ and $Y$ are then conditionally independent given $Z,.$

@KurtG. It is an exercise on Measure Theory, Probability, and Stochastic Processes (Jean-François Le Gall) p253.(Not p259,sorry for my mistake)

No problem. I think I know now what I missed: when we condition on $Z$ we want $\frac{p(x,y,z)}{q(z)}$ to be the joint conditional density of $X$ and $Y,.$ The division by $q(z)$ ensures that we get one when we integrate over $x$ and $y,.$ The rest of the proof is as I said in the comment above. In other words: for fixed $z$ we have $\frac{p(x,y,z)}{q(z)}=r(z,x)s(z,y)$ which says nothing else that $X,Y$ are conditionally independent.

@KurtG. Is your comment above a sketch of the proof for the "$(2)\Rightarrow (1)$" direction?If not, I still don't understand why one can write "$\frac{p(x,y,z)}{q(z)}=r(z,x)s(z,y)$" when $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent given $Z$.

Here is one approach to prove $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$. Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be Borel sets in $\mathbb R$. Writing $p(x,z)$ for the joint density of $(X,Z)$, use this result to see that:
$$P(X\in A\mid Z)=g(Z)\qquad\text{where}\qquad g(z):=\int_A\frac{p(x,z)}{q(z)}dx.\tag{$\ast$}$$ Similarly we have
$$P(Y\in B\mid Z)=h(Z)\qquad\text{where}\qquad h(z):=\int_B\frac{p(y,z)}{q(z)}dy.\tag{$\ast\ast$}$$
Now consider
$$\begin{aligned}
P(X\in A, Y\in B, Z\in C)&=E[ I_A(X) I_B(Y) I_C(Z)]\\
&\stackrel{(1)}=E\left[I_C(Z) E(I_A(X)I_B(Y)\mid Z) \right]\\
&\stackrel{(2)}=E\left[I_C(Z) E(I_A(X)\mid Z) E(I_B(Y)\mid Z) \right]\\
&\stackrel{(3)}=E\left[I_C(Z) g(Z)h(Z)\right]\\
&=\int_C q(z)g(z)h(z)\,dz\\
&\stackrel{(4)}=\int_C q(z)\left(\int_A\frac{p(x,z)}{q(z)}\,dx\right)\left( \int_B\frac{p(y,z)}{q(z)}\,dy\right)\,dz\\
&\stackrel{(5)}=\iiint_{A\times B\times C}q(z)r(z,x)s(z,y)\,dx\,dy\,dz
\end{aligned}
$$ with obvious identifications for $r(z,x)$ and $s(z,y)$. In step (1) we  condition on $\sigma(Z)$ and factor out $I_C(Z)$; step (2) is the definition of conditional independence of $X$ and $Y$ given $\sigma(Z)$; in step (3) and (4) we substitute $(\ast)$ and $(\ast\ast)$; step (5) is Fubini.
But also we have
$$P(X\in A,Y\in B, Z\in C)=\iiint_{A\times B\times C}p(x,y,z)dx\,dy\,dz.$$ Since $A$, $B$, $C$ are arbitrary the assertion follows by identification.
